# Any idea why its not working?

Tags: angularjs

```js
 vm.cancel = function () {
        $("#inlinegridPopup").data("kendoWindow").close();
        return false;
    }
```

```
vm.cancel = function () {
window.jQuery***strong text***("#inlinegridPopup").data("kendoWindow").close();
return false;
}
```

Kendo popup does not closing for me.

Comment: Better edit your Question title.No one can think what you want by reading Title.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure `cancel` function is being called? Try to log something inside `cancel` or set a `debugger` inside.